# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_webhook'

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, discord

So I have a docker container which is trying to use a python module called discord_webhook, to integrate my web service to discord, however when I start the container, it instantly errors out saying

```
houdini_blizzard_1  |   File "/usr/src/houdini/houdini/plugins/discordwebhook/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
houdini_blizzard_1  |     from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
houdini_blizzard_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_webhook'
```

I used docker exec -it {container-id} sh to connect to the container, and ran pip install discord_webhook. It installed fine with no errors. But I then I added discord_webhook module back to the `__init__.py` of the plugin, then restarted the docker container, but it still gave the same error. When I `ls` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord_webhook` there are these files/folders

```
__init__.py  __main__.py  __pycache__  webhook.py
```

That should mean that discord_webhook is installed properly. So why is python saying the module isn't found?

Answer (score 1):

Use dhooks module and the discord module

To send a message using the webhook do

```py
from dhooks import Webhook

hook = Webhook('Your Webhook URL here')

hook.send('Your message here')
```

To send a embed do

```py
import discord
from dhooks import Webhook

hook = Webhook('Hook URL')

embed = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='Description')

hook.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your docker container using `docker-compose up --build`, with discord-webhook in your requirements.txt for your python script.